# SQL Query to fetch id`s who only use that one server IP and not other IP`s

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have one table as below.

```
empid     IP
101       101.105.65.15
102       102.125.68.25
103       205.194.55.86
101       102.125.68.25
103       102.125.68.25
104       102.125.68.25
102       102.125.68.25
```

The above is the table where different employees work on different server`s (IP`s). 
So the problem here is, I need those employees who only work on the IP "102.125.68.25" and not on anything else. In this case it should be employee id 102 and 104.

This is been bugging me for a week now. Hope you guys understood and could help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: `SELECT DISTNCT id from lets_assume_it_is_a_table tt where exists (select * from ztable x where x.ip = tt.ip AND id = this) and not exists (select * from ztable nx where nx.id = nx.id = tt.id and nxip <> the_ip);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IP is known use a Correlated Subquery:

```
select empid
from tab as t1 
where  ip = '102.125.68.25' 
and not exists -- no other ip
 ( select * from tab as t2
   where t1.empid = t2.empid
     and t1.ip <> t2.ip
 )
```

Otherwise a `GROUP BY`:

```
select empid
from tab
group by empid
having min(ip) = max(ip) -- only 1 ip-address
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you guys are the best

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT empid, IP FROM Table
WHERE IP = '102.125.68.25'
AND empid NOT IN (SELECT empid FROM Table WHERE NOT IP = '102.125.68.25')
GROUP BY empid, IP;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you guys are the best.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a count distinct:

```
select empid
from <table>
group by empid
having count (distinct IP) = 1
```

Results:

```
102
104
```